# how to declare a string in a parameter object and then return the string in a get method?

Tags: java

I need a void setSupplementalInsurance(InsurancePolicy policy) method to sets a supplemental insurance policy for the policy. and a InsurancePolicy getSupplementalInsurance(): returns the supplemental insurance policy for the policy, if one exists. Some bugs occur when I enter a string into the object's parameter.

```
public class InsurancePolicy{
  String s1 = "additional policy";
public InsurancePolicy(String s1){
      this.s1=s1;
  }
  InsurancePolicy j=new InsurancePolicy(s1);

public void setSupplementalInsurance(InsurancePolicy policy){
    this.j=policy;
  }

 public InsurancePolicy getSupplementalInsurance(){
    return j;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use meaningful variable name. I am assuming `j` is `supplementalInsurance`.

Comment: *"Some bugs occur"* - Perhaps you could be more specific?

Comment: Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is /Users/a13875810600/Desktop
> InsurancePolicy j=new InsurancePolicy(s1)
Static Error: Undefined name 's1'
>

Comment: do anyone knows how to solve this kind of problem in the interaction pane

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code you're using to initialize the object (formatted for readability):

```
String s1 = "additional policy";
InsurancePolicy j = new InsurancePolicy(s1);

public InsurancePolicy(String s1){
    this.s1 = s1;
}
```

The technical problem here is on the second line (the initialization of the `j` member variable), because you can't use a class member (`s1` in this case) to initialize another class member (`j` in this case) in this way.  The provided value would need to be a compile-time constant, such as the literal string `"additional policy"` on the previous line.

The *conceptual* problem however is that the default value isn't even really needed here and is making for some duplicated logic.  The class has only one constructor, and that constructor has a `String` parameter.  So any time an instance of the class is created, a `String` is required.

Thus you can solve both the conceptual and the technical problem at once.  The conceptual problem is solved in that you can always rely on the provided value and don't need a default value.  And the technical problem is solved in that you can initialize your class member in the constructor instead of at the class level.  For example:

```
String s1;
InsurancePolicy j;

public InsurancePolicy(String s1){
    this.s1 = s1;
    this.j = new InsurancePolicy(s1);
}
```

A couple things to note in this case as well:

- Class members like this should probably be explicitly `private` as well.  If external access to these members is needed, create getter/setter methods.  Your class appears to have such methods for `j` already, which is a good start.
- Consider adding logic to the constructor to validate the provided `String` value if necessary.  That is, to protect against `null` or empty string or anything else that may otherwise break the logic downstream.
- If the `String` value used to initialize `InsurancePolicy` can also be derived from an `InsurancePolicy` object (and I see no reason why it shouldn't) then you are duplicating your data here.  The class member `s1` is *most likely* not needed at all and should be removed.